# Find element on webpage with Python 2.7 requests

Tags: html, python-2.7

I need to see if an element is on a page, more specifically, I am trying to locate the element that means my proxy IP is banned in my request session.

So far I have tried:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
page = requests.get("http://www.adidas.com/us")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
html_element = tree.xpath(".//span[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lblInvalidRequest']")
```

Comment: Can you not check the status code of the response to find out if the IP is banned?

Comment: So? You tried and what? Edit your question